# How can I use a Presale JSON file to keep my ETH long-term in cold storage and sell my ETC seperately?

Tags: ethereum-classic, myetherwallet, presale

I received Ether during the Pre-sale in June 2014 and received a JSON file and have the password. I have never tried to access these funds. I found out that I should have ETC & ETH due to the hard-fork in 2016 due to the DAO hack. My question is, what is the safest way to keep the ETH and sell the ETC or trade it for more ETH in July 2017?

Some posts mentioned to Split the funds by firstly creating a new ETC & ETH account by using something like My Ether Wallet (MEW). I then need to access the funds via the JSON file on the ETC & ETH blockchains seperately in MEW. On each chain (ETH & ETC) you then need to move the funds from the presale wallet to the new ETH & ETC accounts. Due to EIP-155 My Ether Wallet (MEW) should have replay protection so it should be as simple as that. Is this logic flawed in anyway? I am very worried that I do something wrong and lose any of the ETH or ETC. What would be the steps if I had to do this process via the official Ethereum Wallet on www.ethereum.org (Geth I think) or Mist?

If I keep the JSON file for another few years without accessing the funds will I still be able to access it or is it better to split it? I was thinking of getting maybe a hardware wallet if it is required to split it.

Comment: I have the same question. Were you able to find a solution? I have gone through a number of trials and was unable to take the time to claim my presale. If someone could be kind enough to answer this question, I would be grateful. I only have a small amount invested, but it would help with family medical bills. Blessings!

Comment: Yes, I found a solution. 1st use MEW and make sure to point it to the ETC chain. Then unlock the pre-sale JSON file using MEW which should then show your ETC balance. What I did was to make a transfer to Changelly to convert the ETC into ETH. I created a new ETH wallet to be able to receive the ETH that I will get and did not put it in my pre-sale ETH wallet. That's it. I left my pre-sale ETH where it was and will keep it for a few more years.